# returning multiple strings from a function

Tags: c++, string, return

I have a function where i want to be able return what is printed out so then i can print the output on the page. How will i return both of the string which are outputted within both of those if statements ?

```
 std::vector<std::string> el;
      split(el,message,boost::is_any_of("\n"));
      std::string a ("");

          for(int i = 0; i < el.size(); i++)
          {
              if(el[i].substr(0,3) == ".X/")
              {
                  DCS_LOG_DEBUG("--------------- Validating .X/ ---------------")
                  std::string str = el[i].substr(3);
                  std::vector<std::string>st;
                  split(st,str,boost::is_any_of("/"));
                  boost::regex const string_matcher(splitMask[0]);
                  if(boost::regex_match(st[0],string_matcher))
                  {
                      a = "Correct Security Instruction";

                  }
                  else
                  {
                      a = "Incorrect Security Instruction" 
                  }

                  boost::regex const string_matcher1(splitMask[1]);
                  if(boost::regex_match(st[1],string_matcher1))
                  {
                     a = "Correct Security screening result" 
                  }
                  else
                  {
                      a = "Incorrect Security screening result" 
                  }


                  return a;

              }

          }
```

Thankfull for any help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can push the strings in a std::vector that is passed to the function as a reference and later iterate over the vector upon return.

Answer (score 3):

You can return an `std::pair` of strings, for instance.

Answer (score 3):

Define a class with two appropriately-named string members and return an instance of that.

Then, start to think about what methods or other data would be useful to have on that class.

Answer (score 0):

I would return a `std::pair` of `bool` values (one to indicate if the instruction is correct, and one to indicate if the screening result is correct), and let the calling code interpret the results.